Surround Sound Problems with PipeWire
I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.4 LTS inside 3 computers, 2 desktops and 1 laptop.
As we know, this Ubuntu Studio version doesn't have a PipeWire Audio Server installation full activated. SO... I try to activate it, inside the laptop device, with a "not official" way.
It works... Almost.
But... I discovered a problem with audio/video apps with surround sound capabilities (like MPV Player).
The laptop only have one standard stereo audio output. So, to get all the surround sound channels inside that stereo output, I connect it through jack facilities as in this scheme:

The same scheme works so fine inside the 2 desktop computers, without the full PipeWire activation.
BUT... In the laptop with PipeWire, there is a noticeable narrowing effect of the any original stereo image audio file.
This effect is caused by a weird mixdown between the front and rear central surround channels with the front left and front right stereo channels. That mixdown reduces the full original stereo separation.
The only way I found to avoid that effect, is to disconnect the front and rear central surround channels at all.

With the last scheme I get the full original stereo image, BUT... I lose the central channels (if I use any surround sound source).
SO... It is just a partial solution.
The weird mixdown is somewhere between the PipeWire and PulseAudio servers.
I want to know if there is a way to full fix this problem avoiding that weird mixdown.
Any Idea, please? ???

As you have used some unofficial way I do not see how anyone here can help you. Maybe try and contact someone involved with this unofficial way.

I think I wrote the wrong words. I didn't mean I use some "unofficial" (hacker) way to install and activate it. I wanted to say I forced the installation, because 22.04.4 LTS doesn't make it by default. Pipewire is working, almost fine. I discovered some issues with some specific apps (like qtractor), but it is due those apps don't have been upgraded yet, because the whole system doesn't have been upgraded. But, back to the central point, I think it is something related with some Pipewire configuration file, which I don't have any clue how to edit and where it was. Whatever, thanks a lot!!!

Please edit the question and correct any wording you feel is wrong. Comments do not always get read or stay around.
